# How to do a (trapeze) integration in Python without any import?

Tags: python, math

[image]

I Would like to write a function that receives as parameters:
function f, (X0,Xn), and number of trapezes - and returns the estimated value of the integrartion of f.

```
def f1(x):
    return x * 4 * (1 - x) * 4 / (1 + x ** 2)

def f2(x):
    e = 2.718281828459045
    return e ** -x

def integral(f, interval, n):
    ''' computes estimate of integral of f over interval based on deviding interval into n trapeziums '''
    if not (callable(f) and isinstance(interval, tuple) and isinstance(n, int)):
        ## callable(f) is true if f is a function. isinstance(interval, tuple) is true if interval is of type tuple
        return
    if not (len(interval)==2 and isinstance(interval[0], float) and isinstance(interval[1], float) \
            and interval[0]<interval[1]):
        return
    ### the code should go here
    return 0.0 # returning 0.0, change to proper return value 
    ### end of the code

print(integral(lambda x : x, (1.0, 2.0), 100))   ## should be close to 1.5
```

Comment: try checking previous people's implementation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46516967/integrate-a-function-by-the-trapezoidal-rule-python